# No me funciona el else de mi if

Tags: c++, condiciones

Tengo un problema que parece sencillo pero no consigo averiguar porqué me falla, resulta que tengo un programa para simular una base de datos médica que consiste en  añadir, ver y eliminar medicos, el tema es que en la opción "Ver medicos" utilizo un if para saber si previamente se han añadido médicos dado que de no ser así no se puede visualizar nada, el problema viene en el if que uso para comprobarlo no me funciona el else:

```
case 2: //Enseñamos todos los medicos

                //Comprobamos que haya medicos registrados en la base de datos

                if(nro_medicos > 0){
                    VerMedicos();
                }
                else{
                    cout<<"Error"<<endl;
                    cout<<"No hay médicos registrados en la base de datos"<<endl;
                }

                break;
```

Este es el fragmento donde está metida la función que visualiza los médicos y el if que falla, cuando voy a ejecutar el programa y selecciono el 2 sin añadir médicos no funciona...

Comment: Has revisado que la variable `nro_medicos` esté inicializada en 0 y que su valor no se ha modificado? Como depuración podrías hacer un cout << nro_medicos; antes del `if`

Comment: Deberías mostrar un [mcve] (y recalco lo de **mínimo**) que reproduzca tu problema. Con la **extremadamente poca** información que das, ofrecer una respuesta es imposible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podrias intentar hacer lo inverso, es decir algo como:

```
if(nro_medicos <= 0){
    cout<<"Error"<<endl;
    cout<<"No hay médicos registrados en la base de datos"<<endl;
}
else{
    VerMedicos();
}
```

espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Primero Validá si la variable tiene datos, así si no lo tiene puede pasar por el else

```
if(nro_medicos!=null && nro_medicos > 0){...
```